# How to make inline responsive element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code:

```
<div class="logo-social-box">            <!--Main Container-->
  <div class="logo"></div>               <!--First Div-->
  <div class="social-box"></div>         <!--Second Div-->
</div>
```

I want to set `.logo` and `.social-box` inline without using float property and these elements should be responsive.

Comment: What's wrong with using `float`?  (as per the question title "without using float" but the reason is not mentioned in the question)

Comment: Making the element responsive is not mutually exclusive with `float` - you can do both. The alternative to float would be to position them absolutely, although this causes a different set of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: flex`

```css
.logo-social-box {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-social-box .logo {
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
}

.logo-social-box .social-box {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-social-box">
  <div class="logo">            <!--First Div-->
  </div>
  <div class="social-box">      <!--Second Div-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LGSon this question is one the asked question in here (I'd give you the `without float` part)  but still the answers now "use flex" ;)